# How can I provide a scala companion object's class to Java?

Tags: scala, static-methods, scala-java-interop

I have a Java code that looks for annotations in static methods of a class.

```
processor.readStatics( MyClass.class );  // Takes Class<?>
```

How can I provide the methods of a scala companion object to this function from within scala?

```
class MyClass {
}
object MyClass {
  def hello() { println("Hello (object)") } 
}
```

I seems that:

```
MyClass$.MODULE$.getClass()
```

should be the [answer](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~michelou/scala/using-scala-from-java.html). However, MyClass$ seems to be missing from scala (in 2.10, at least) and only visible to Java.

```
println( Class.forName("MyClass$.MODULE$") )
```

also fails.

Comment: Have you tried `Class.forName("MyClass$MODULE$")`? For inner classes no need for additional `.`.

Comment: Or `Class.forName("MyClass$$MODULE$")`, because we have to use `$` instead of `.` for inner classes.

Comment: Hmm it might be enough to use the class returned by `Class.forName(MyClass$)`. At least it is found with Scala 2.10.3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Class name is `MyClass$` (with the appropriate package name prepended).

`println(Class.forName("MyClass$"))` will print out "class MyClass$".

`MyClass$.MODULE$` is the *instance* of the class, referencing the singleton object.

`println(MyClass$.MODULE$ == MyClass)` will print out "true" even though, when compiling, you will get a warning that this comparison always yields false :)

Note, that none of this works in repl for some reason. You need to actually create a .scala file, compile it with scalac, and run.

So, in java, use `MyClass$` to reference the class of `MyClass` object statically, use `MyClass$.MODULE$` to reference the singleton instance of `MyClass` object, use `MyClass$.class` or `MyClass$.MODULE$.getClass()` to reference the class of the singleton object dynamically, use `Class.forName("MyClass$")` to access it at runtime by name.

Answer (score 2):

The shortest and type-safest solution is to simply use

```
MyClass.getClass
```

I would have hoped the following to work, but apparently `scalac` is not happy with it:

```
classOf[MyClass.type]
```